# AutoHotkey detect keypress and send the pressed key without calling the function again

Tags: autohotkey

Okay, so my problem is rather simple, I have tried searching but was unable to find anything.

My code is like this:

```
T::
Send t
if(x=0)
y=1
Return
```

It creates a loop, which is pretty obvious to see.
I have tried adding:

```
T::
if(tx=0){
Send t
tx=1
}else{
tx=0
}
if(x=0)
y=1
Return
```

But that wont do it either, so my question is, is there a way to detect when the keypress was generated by the script or by the keyboard itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a <kbd>$</kbd> infront of your hotkey <kbd>t</kbd>, like this `$t::`, it will no longer be triggered by the script itself. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I were sure it was something simple, I don't know tried searching on google on what keywords I thought would find the answer, but didn't work, anyways thanks! :)